# recursetree code not working

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

I'm trying to fix a bug that appeared on a website I'm maintaining www.kenyabuzz.com the top navigation won't get the children elements. This is the code for the top nav I think `{{ children }}` is missing.

```
      {% recursetree top_menu %}
      <li{% if node.slug == '' %} id="nav-home"{% endif %} class="stackAuto">
        <a href="{% if node.url_override %}{{ node.url_override }}{% else %}{{ node.get_absolute_url }}{% endif %}" title="{{ node.title }}" class="stackContent{% if node.id == page.id or node.id == page.parent.id %} current{% endif %}">
          {% if node.slug == '' %}<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}kb/img/kenya-buzz-logo.gif" alt="Home" />{% else %}{{ node.name }}{% endif %}
        </a>
      </li>
      {% endrecursetree %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely `{{ children }}` is missing. Your code could be for example:

```
{% recursetree top_menu %}
<li{% if node.slug == '' %} id="nav-home"{% endif %} class="stackAuto">
    <a href="{% if node.url_override %}{{ node.url_override }}{% else %}{{ node.get_absolute_url }}{% endif %}" title="{{ node.title }}" class="stackContent{% if node.id == page.id or node.id == page.parent.id %} current{% endif %}">
    {% if node.slug == '' %}<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}kb/img/kenya-buzz-logo.gif" alt="Home" />{% else %}{{ node.name }}{% endif %}
    </a>
    {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
        <ul class="menu children">
            {{ children }}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
</li>
{% endrecursetree %}
```